# Silverlight Binding to commands

Tags: silverlight, binding, command

Sometimes when I bind to commands to a ViewModel, my CanExecute code does not always get called and hence my buttons are not disabled when they should be.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When canExecute is not called the **first time**, that's a binding problem.

If it's not 'automatically' called second,[n]th time, that's the normal behavior.

Imagine, **how the UI should know** that it should requery your predicate? When you have a **command parameter** it will call your predicate every time the parameter changes. Generally, some UI 'events' also requery it (focus, updatelayout etc), but **not always** (that's good, it would be pointless to reevaluate every command binding all time). So you cannot rely on it. You make the business logic, so **you know** when it needs an update, not the UI. The UI 'cannot see inside your predicate delegate' and watch what happens. You have to **notify** the UI about it, same as you notify when a **property changed**.

**ICommand** has an event, so you must implement it, it's the **CanExecuteChanged**.

You should implement a public method to fire it (or it is already implemented if you use a framework, like MVVMLight or Prism).

A simple implementation.

```
public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

So you can call it on your command whenever your canExecute state changes in your business logic and it is going to **notify** all the subscribers, which is **your button** in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You mention the state of the button not being disabled.  This seems more like a binding issue than binding to commands.  Is the state of the property you are binding to changing?  When is it changing, etc.?

Comment: The button is not binding to anything, only its Command property

Comment: @Jared Peless: If a control implements ICommand then it will typically listen to the `CanExecute` event on that interface and enable/disable the control accordingly.